# Can you add session data in controller?

Tags: laravel, session

I tried to use socialite on laravel and it works, I got the user data from google callback and I wanted to store the user data in session after the callback

```
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
session(['user' => $user]);
```

but the user data is lost after redirect, I can't access it on view

I've tried to use middleware but it doesn't help, user data is still not there

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: oops my bad, ill delete it

Comment: Which session driver do you use?

Comment: @DasunTharanga i use file driver

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;
$request->session()->keep(['user]);
you can use session name after assigning a value to keep session data after multiple requests
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#flash-data

Comment: What’s the error you are getting did you use Session::put(key, val)?

Comment: @Sumitkumar I didn't get any error, it just that the session user data is not exist on view. If I dd(session('user')) on the controller, the user data exist, but not on the view after redirect

Comment: @Sumitkumar I add the user data with session(['user' => $user]);

Comment: @Shailendra I tried to use keep('user') but its not working

Comment: @Han then you should try the session in the old fashioned PHP way using **session_start()** and **$_SESSION** variables

Comment: @Shailendra turns out I do something with the config file, and it messes everything up hahaha, the problem is solved, thanks for the answers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by changing the SESSION_DOMAIN on config/session.php from

```
SESSION_DOMAIN="http://localhost:8000"
```

to

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=null
```

thanks to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-persist-session-after-redirect-route

thanks everyone for the answers! :D

Comment: `SESSION_DOMAIN` isn't set by default so it ends up as `null` on a default setup ... always good to go back to defaults if you run into some odd problems